# Powershell log deleted files

Tags: file, powershell, logging, delete-file

**The script searches all folders and subfolders and delete the oldest file when the number of files is>5. Everything works fine, but I want also log all the delete Files as a record in a log-file.**

How can I log the deleted files ?

Here the Script.

```
$path = "C:\test\1"
$keep = 3
$strLogFileName   = "c:\test\yourlogfile.log";

$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}
foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.name -like "*.zip"}
    if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
        $files | Sort-Object CreationTime -desc| Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | Remove-Item -Force 
    ***{write-host “Deleting File $File” -foregroundcolor “Red”; Remove-Item $File | out-null}*** 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a good start here:

```
write-host “Deleting File $File” -foregroundcolor “Red”
```

Unfortunately `Remove-Item` doesn't have any output that you can mooch from, but you've already made your own output message so we can just build from that.  You can pipe any output to a file by using `Out-File`.  The append flag will attach the new content to the end of the file, and you do not have to check if the file exists.

```
Write-Output “Deleting File $File” | Out-File -Append logfile.txt
```

You don't even have to include Write-Output, if you want a shorter line.

Here is an example that shows where you need to add code. I've marked existing code with "...", and I've moved the deletion message into a variable so that you can reuse it at another location. This assumes that you've stored the selected filename in a variable.

```
...
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) 
{
    ...
    $message = "Deleting File $File at "+(Get-Date)
    $message | Out-File -Append logfile.txt 
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

First you will need a `log-message` type function in your script that will log the message to a .log file. Then chekc if the file exists and if not then create a file.

Then just before you delete your file with `Remove-Item` command you can use `Log-Message` function to log message to the log file.

```
% { (Log-Message "Deleting File $_"); $_ }
```

Complete script

```
$path = "C:\test\1"
$keep = 3
$strLogFileName   = "c:\test\yourlogfile.log";

function Log-Message
{
   Param ([string]$logtext)
   Add-content $strLogFileName -value $logtext
}

$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}
foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.name -like "*.zip"}
    if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
        $files | Sort-Object CreationTime -desc| Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | 
        % { $dt=get-date;(Log-Message "Deleting File $_  on  $dt");$_ }| Remove-Item -Force 

    }
}
```

Comment: O.k seem like perfect but can you tell how can i add the Datetime for the delete file for each file to into the Log ??

Comment: you are really god with powershell :) One last question, how can I delete only the oldest file and not the newest ? Many thx for your help

Comment: Thx i have found it: Sort-Object LastWriteTime

Comment: I need your help once again. Now the zip files should not be deleted but the folders which are one level higer. Here the Folder path:\\xxx\xu_207\Archiv\20080101 can you help me again ? Many thx

Comment: @zero1de You should ask this new problem in a new question and upvote and/or accept answers that solved your previous problem. Stringing Mitul along without crediting him appropriately is very rude and may discourage users from helping you in the future.